# C# foreach on IEnumerable<IList<object>> compiles but shouldn't

Tags: c#, generics, nested-generics

I have the following code:

```
IEnumerable<IList<MyClass>> myData = //...getMyData

foreach (MyClass o in myData)
{
    // do something
}
```

It compiles, runs and obviously I get an `System.InvalidCastException`.
Why does the compiler not complain? `MyClass` is a simple bean, no extensions.

Edit 1:
As suggested by David switching the type from `IList` to `List` the compiler complains

Edit 2:
I've understood that the behaviour is as specified in the [C# Language definition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029). However, I don't understand why such a cast/conversion is allowed, since at runtime I always get an InvalidCastException. I opened [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53591187/explanation-for-c-sharp-language-specification-6-2-4-explicit-reference-convers) in order to go deeper.

Comment: Note: While replicating this issue, changing from `IList` to `List` produces the compile-time error.  Also, while it's still `IList`, doing this produces the compile-time error: `MyClass x = myData.First();`

Comment: You get a "suspicious cast" with resharper

Comment: @David you are right, but I expect the compiler recognizes the error even with the IList.

Comment: @Emaborsa: Agreed, and the responses below have been enlightening for me on the subject.  Just adding to the info, since I found this one pretty interesting.

Comment: @Emaborsa: the compiler does not do this code analysis(while resharper does it). Because actually it's possible that there is a type which inherits from `MyClass` and also implements `IList<MyClass>`. The compiler does not check what you assign, it checks the declared type on the left side. The code would be perfectly valid if you'd assign `new List<MyClassChild>()` and `MyClassChild` was a child and implemented `IList<MyClass>`.

Comment: @Rango Outside of a `foreach` that would still require a downcast though. That is, it's not legal to write `MyClass foo = myData.GetEnumerator().Current;` - it would need an explicit cast to `MyClass`. Downcasts aren't usually implicit. So the question remains why `foreach` inserts such a cast automatically. I assume the answer is so users were able to write `foreach (MyType x in myUntypedList)` in the days before generics.

Comment: @sepp2k: `foreach` always had a builtin explicit cast, they can enumerate `List<Object>` and cast to whatever you specify in the loop variable-type. That will fail at runtime. Of course the reason is that the `foreach` is much older than generics.

Comment: @Rango I feel like that should be the answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IList<MyClass>` *is* convertible to `MyClass`.

But if you actually run it with a non-empty enumerable,

```
IEnumerable<IList<MyClass>> myData = new IList<MyClass>[1] { new List<MyClass>() {new MyClass()}};
```

You get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyClass]' to type 'MyClass'.

This is in compliance with the spec:

> Section 8.8.4 The foreach statement
>
> ...
>   If there is not an explicit conversion (§6.2) from T (the element
>   type) to V (the local-variable-type in the foreach statement), an
>   error is produced and no further steps are taken.
>
> ...

There *is* an explicit conversion from `IList<MyClass>` to `MyClass` (though it will fail at runtime), so no error is produced.

> Section 6.2.4 Explicit reference conversions
>
> The explicit reference conversions are:
>
> - From object and dynamic to any other reference-type.
> - From any class-type S to any class-type T, provided S is a base class of T.
> - From any class-type S to any interface-type T, provided S is not sealed and provided S does not implement T.
> - *From any interface-type S to any class-type T, provided T is not sealed or provided T implements S.*
>
> ...

Comment: I think the third statement is what I was looking for. However, I don't really get the meaning of it.

Comment: @Emaborsa The third statement of what? Can you quote it so I can explain?

Comment: I thought you ment `From any class-type S to any interface-type T, provided S is not sealed and provided S does not implement T` as answer to my question.

Comment: @Emaborsa Ah! I copied the wrong thing. Added the corrected one: `From any interface-type S to any class-type T, provided T is not sealed or provided T implements S.` `MyClass` is not sealed. So you can convert from any interface to `MyClass`.

Comment: Well, I understand what it means...but I don't understand why such a conversion is allowed.

Comment: @Emaborsa let’s say you have a variable of type `IList<MyClass>` called `x`. At runtime, you might assign an instance of a subclass of `MyClass`, which implements `IList<MyClass>`, to `x`. In situation, `(MyClass)x` will succeed.

Comment: If we talk about inheritance it is ok. My doubts are about the `not sealed` part of the statement.

Comment: @Emaborsa this only works if the class is not sealed. If the class is sealed, then it cannot have subclasses, which eliminates the possibility of the variable actually storing a subclass of the class that implements the interface.

Comment: Yes I understand, but give me an example where such a casting is needed where T is NOT sealed and T does NOT implement S.

Comment: @Emaborsa I can’t give you an actual example in production code because I have never encountered such situations myself. Here’s a hypothetical one: you have a variable of type `IFlyable` interface and a `Bird` abstract class. Not all birds can fly so `Bird` does not implement `IFlyable`. You want to run some code only if the variable stores a `Bird` but you don’t care if it is  `Sparrow` or `Owl` or some other bird that can fly. So you check whether that variable `is Bird` and then cast from `IFlyable` to `Bird`.

Comment: For me it does not make any sense, I needed further explanation and opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53591187/explanation-for-c-sharp-language-specification-6-2-4-explicit-reference-convers

Answer (score 6):

Well because `IList<MyClass>` is an interface so theoretically you could have a class that implemented that interface AND derives from `MyClass`.

If you change it to `IEnumerable<List<MyClass>>` it will not compile.

In any case, at least I'm getting a warning for suspicious cast, as there is no class in the solution which inherits from both `IList<MyClass>` and `MyClass`.

Comment: _"I'm getting a warning for suspicious cast"_ but that' from resharper isn't it?

Comment: @Rango It could, tbh it looks like a native warning but I've been working with resharper so long that I can't notice the difference.

Comment: Not a Native warning. I have stock VS 2017 and it shows no errors or warnings.

Comment: @Liam it must be Resharper then

Answer (score 5):

When a `foreach` is compiled it follows a pattern not specific types (much as LINQ and `await` do).

`foreach` isn't looking for an `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` but for a type which has a `GetEnumerator()` method (which `IList<T>` does). And the objects in the outer list could be of a type derived from `MyClass` and implementing `IList<T>`).

Ie. the compiler does a lightweight "matches the pattern" check not a complete check.

See §8.8.3 of the C#5 Language Specification which covers this in detail (and you'll see I've rather simplified things above: even `IEnumerator` isn't checked for, just that there is a `MoveNext()` method and a `Current` property).

Answer (score 2):

Under the assumption that `MyClass` does not implement `IList<MyClass>`, there could be a derived type of `MyClass` that does implement `IList<MyClass>` and then your loop would be valid.

That is,

```
class MyClass
{
}

class Derived : MyClass, IList<MyClass>
{
    // ...
}

// ...

// Here IList<MyClass> is Derived, which is valid because Derived implements IList<MyClass>
IEnumerable<IList<MyClass>> myData = new []{new Derived()};

// Here MyClass is Derived, which is valid because Derived inherits from MyClass
foreach (MyClass o in myData)
{
    // do something
}
```