# Explanation for C# Language Specification: 6.2.4 Explicit reference conversions

Tags: definition, c#-5.0, explicit-conversion

As I mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53559287/c-sharp-foreach-on-ienumerableilistobject-compiles-but-shouldnt/) post, I faced a for me not understandable compiler behaviour.

The code:

```
IEnumerable<IList<MyClass>> myData = //...getMyData
foreach (MyClass o in myData){}
```

It compiles, but fails on runtime: InvalidCastException; for me it is obvious.

If I change the `IList` to `List` as following, it complains:

```
IEnumerable<List<MyClass>> myData = //...getMyData
foreach (MyClass o in myData){}
```

When instead of the class type I put `var` as following, intellisense recognizes the correct type:

```
IEnumerable<List<MyClass>> myData = //...getMyData
foreach (var o in myData){}
```

My first question was: Why doesn't the compiler complain? The answer was that the behaviour respects the [C# Language definition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029). See chapter 6.2.4 Explicit reference conversions, page 116.

Read the 4th and 5th statement:

> • From any interface-type S to any class-type T, provided T is not sealed or provided T implements S.
>
> • From any interface-type S to any interface-type T, provided S is not derived from T.

For the second part of the first statement `provided T implements S` is clear, no doubts.
 But why might we cast an interface-type S to **any** class-type T if it is **not** derived or **not** implemented?
In which case/scenario with an non empty list would the code run without throwing an `InvalidCastException`?

Comment: It is the .NET 1.0 tax.  IList also implements IEnumerable.  The non-generic one that spits out collection members of type `object`.  Which *might* be convertible to MyClass.  C# would look very different if 1.0 never happened.